# Difference between 'self.method_name' and 'class << self' in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4.2.1, I've added a custom folder `m1` in another folder `services` at `app/services/m1`. In this folder I've added three files corresponding to three classes: `app/services/m1/c1.rb`, `app/services/m1/c2.rb` and `app/services/m1/c3.rb`. The contents of each of these files are as follows:

```
# app/services/m1/c1.rb
module M1
  class C1
    def self.foo1
      C2.foo2
    end
  end
end


# app/services/m1/c2.rb
module M1
  class C2
    class << self
      def foo2
        return 123
      end
    end
  end
end


# app/services/m1/c3.rb
module M1
  class C3
    class << self
      def foo1
        C2.foo2
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, in the Rails console, when I do the following:

```
# First Command
M1::C3.foo1
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant C2
from /path_to_the_app_directory/app/services/m1/c3.rb:5:in `foo1
```

But, when I do this, just after the above command:

```
# Second Command
M1::C1.foo1
```

I get `123` as the result. And when immediately after this, if I do the following:

```
# Third Command, same as First Command
M1::C3.foo1
```

I get `123` as the correct result.
So, why is there a difference between `foo1` methods of class `C1` and `C3` ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not in the way you defined the class methods, both ways are equivalent. Maybe the issue is that you did not add the `app/services` directory to autoload paths:

```
# config/application.rb

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/services)

    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I add `/app/services` to `autoload_paths`. I also tried to add `/app/services/m1` to `autoload_paths`, the error changed to: 
`LoadError: Unable to autoload constant C2, expected /path_to_app_directory/app/services/m1/c2.rb to define it
from /path_to_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in 'load_missing_constant'`